# Something fried in PSU, but PC still works?

Tags: boot, power-supply

I just finished cleaning the dust from my desktop PC with compressed air. When I put everything back together and plugged it to power, there was a brief flash of light and another after I booted it. After the second one, there was a slight smell of burning electronics, but everything seems to work normally. I checked for any burnt components on the devices, but couldn't find any. POST was normal, all devices appear normally in devmgmt, all HDD partitions are accessible, and all memory is still showing.

After some sniffing around, it seems to be coming mainly from the PSU (Corsair HX620). But the strange part is that the computer works normally? If the PSU is fried, I would expect it not to boot?

Is it possible that it was simply a small patch of dust inside the PSU, that burnt up and everything's OK? Or is there a chance that a minor component of the PSU fried and will give trouble later on, possibly a danger of fire? Would it be best to replace the PSU, just to be sure?

Comment: I'm not an electronics specialist, but to my knowledge burning dust smells differently than a burning chip. I would be cautioned about using your computer, because a faulty PSU can damage your other components due to giving out the wrong voltages.

Comment: If it wasn't dust and the PSU is working it's probably a blown capacitor. Check for bulging or leaking caps (they look like a tall cylinder standing on its axis)

Comment: If the PSU is damaged, then it has a high potential to damage everything else in the system at any time. If you're going to mess about inside the PSU, do it very carefully. Even when the power's off, there's still enough electricity in those capacitors to give you a nasty bite.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately stop using the PC !

In my experience, Corsair makes good quality power supplies and often provide a lengthy warranty period. However, eventually all electronics fail.

As the problem occured after cleaning the device with compressed air, the most likely scenarios are:

- dust accumulated on some place below the circuit board, perhaps became damp and made an unsafe path for electricity to flow.
- if you used a compressor, lubricant oil could've short circuited components inside of the power supply
- Less likely, a piece of solder might have come loose.
- one or more capacitors are failing

Never assume everything is right! Disconnect the power supply, inspect it visually outside, inside and use a power supply tester to confirm that the output voltages are within specifications.
It's possible that the fault isn't immediately apparant, some protection circuit for example may have failed.

If the power supply is still within the warranty period, exchange it for a new one.
If it isn't, then ideally open it up and inspect the components.
In any case, replacement is the safest solution (if nothing else has failed inside of your computer as a result of this).